# jquery ajax load (full URL)

Tags: url

hi is there a wait to load a full url.?

```
url= 'http://www.example.com/whatever.php'
$('#selector').load(url);  // this way returns null (empty result)
```

instead of :

```
url = 'whatever.php'
$('#selector').load(url); // works fine
```

Some may think whats the difference i want to use this because im using multiple directories. so i could be on a page like...

```
example.com/dir/
```

but the dir folder will not have the whatever.php
so anyone has a fix for this that i should always use the full url?
thank you.

Comment: I have noticed that the problem is on the "www."
if i remove it like so `url = 'http://example.com/whatever.php'` then it works fine... whats up with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always use relative paths

putting `/` before the path will tell the browser to go the root of the page. For your example you could call `/whatever.php`.

You can also move up one directory at a time. Lets say you are in a page at `http://www.example.com/dir/foo/bar.php` and want to access something in the dir folder, you could specify `../inTheDir.php` to move up one directory or `../../inTheRoot.php` to move up two.

This should work for you, but based on your comment it sounds like you have a problem somewhere else since your `www.` page doesn't seem to respond correctly.

Comment: thats a clever trick... however this could be a silly setting on the www so ... thank you

Answer (score -1):

<del>No, there isn't.</del>

If `http://www.example.com/` takes longer to load than `http://example.com/` then it is probably because you have the DNS record for `example.com` cached but not the record for `www.example.com`.

Corrected after having realized a typo changed the meaning of the question.:

This is a case of having a mismatch between the host name the page is loaded from and the host name the Ajaxed resource is requested from. i.e. The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Pick a host name to be canonical, use that one in your requests, and redirect (with a 301 status code) from the other so that people don't go to the wrong one by mistake.

Comment: `http://www.example.com` does not return anything at all. where as `http://example.com` returns what ever its in it. ... does it have disadvantages by using it without the www ?

Comment: Ooooh. "Wait" was a typo for "Way"